# Maximum number of states in State Pattern

Tags: design-patterns, max, composite, state-pattern

I am trying to use state pattern and i have a question. Is state pattern designed only for situtations with limited number of states like this:

TCPState:
1- TCPEstablished
2- TCPLisenting
3- TCPClosed
etc.

Or it can be used in cases with hundreds of states like for example an employee in an employee attendance system where an employee will have a composite state of multiple components like number of yearly vacations he has in his balance, number of hours he should compensate this month, a state to represent his hourly salary rate depending on the work load for this month, etc. each employee can have combination of multiple attributes that eventually considered to be a state with a certain behavior.

at this case there will be hundrerds of state objects, is that correct thing to do? how would you manage state objects naming? and what would you do if for example one third of the states share a certain behavior for some method, and another quarter shares another behavior for a certain method etc. i.e. not all states necisserly have a unique behavior in all it's methods. I dont think copying the implementation and pasting it into all the states that have the same behavior for this common method would be wise!

Thank you very much.

Comment: Generally, I think you could use the State pattern if you could define a limited number of states using the variables you mention, e.g. 'salary in range 1/2/3', 'more or less than 8 hours to compensate' etc. But it would be better to explain something first about what software you want to build, and why you are considering to use the State pattern in the first place.

Comment: The system is a permit management system to grant access cards to users to access certain locations. the permit will have several attributes that when combined together will form a state that will force certain behavior, that's why i have chosen state pattern. The permit will have a State atrribute (formed of 6 variations) and StoppedState attribute (formed of 3 variations) and an IsPrinted attribute that indicates whether the permit is printed or not. Thank you

Comment: [never mind my previous comment; removed it] From what you write above it seems that the number of different states is already limited (6 plus 3). The fact that the currently active state is chosen based on parameters that are themselves have an unlimited (or very large) number of possible values does not mean that your number of states it not limited.

Comment: Unfortunately the situtation is kinda more complex than the 6 x 3 x 2 possible states explained above, adding all the attributes could raise the state possibilities to 150+ state, i am just trying to keep things simple to deliver the idea without getting much deeper into the business logic.

Answer (score 1):

There is no defined maximum number of 'State' classes, but if you implement a 'State' class for every 'state' you will likely end up with massive code duplication, which is considered a problem on its own.

Note that a 'state' as in *a combination of assigned values* is not the same as a *'State' class* in the State Pattern, which is an implementation of a set of abstract methods. A misnomer if you ask me, a 'State' should better be called a 'Behaviour' in the pattern.

If you can capture the behaviour in a limited set of 'State' classes (i.e. if it can be built with a limited number of lines of code, so probably yes) then you can apply the State Pattern. As you already mention, you can apply the State Pattern multiple times, by maintaining more than one active states.